# how i can access session in route.php in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

how i can access session in route.php in codeigniter 3.0

my application is multi language support so i can used session for language change my application data , lable,static captions language change

now i want to extend my application

means when language change that time url also change means

for example

```
http://localhost/test/en/controller/method
```

when change language in spainsh that time url change like below

```
http://localhost/test/es/controller/method
```

so how i can do this

please help me thanks

Comment: For something like this mind checking out the codeigniter hooks, they can be of great help and seem to be what you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always can access to the `$_SESSION` variable. However, I'm not sure if it's compatible with CodeIgniter Session library.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
   // define your routing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upto the level I understand,You're using **Codeigniter's session data** as an identity to indicate lang and its associated data..?

Codeigniter uses similar way of superglobal session maintainence like using session_start() and $_SESSION.
But It is advised **not** to use session data anywhere else than that of controllers.

Try writing a **Super-controller which extends to all of your controllers**.

```
            class SuperController extends MY_Controller
        {



            public function __construct()
             {
                // Ensure you run parent constructor
                parent::__construct();    
                $this->checkSess();
             }

            public function checkSess() 
           {
              //Your session check and its associated redirects
              //eg. if $this->session->en==1 redirect to eng lang controller



            }

        }

    Class YourController extends SuperController{
    //Your code

}
```

Or You can use multilang suppport in Codeigniter as of in [Codexworld](http://www.codexworld.com/multi-language-implementation-in-codeigniter/)

Or If you want to still use session in routes.php . You can try as of in a standard PHP way as Alexander said.But I doubt whether it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize session in autoload.php like:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

and then in routes.php you can access the sessions as:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```